# MAMP server not working after OS Sierra update

Tags: wordpress, macos, apache, mamp, macos-sierra

I recently updated to the latest version of macOS and can't get an old MAMP-dependent project I have to run. It was working fine right before I upgraded. I googled my way around thinking the upgrade might be something simple like the previous OS upgrade fix that required simply renaming the file but I couldn't fine anything.

Has anyone else had any MAMP issues with the latest macOS update or what are some common local environment fixes to look into after an OS update?

*apache_error_log:*

```
[Sun Nov 27 17:40:12 2016] [notice] FastCGI: process manager          initialized (pid 2517)
[Sun Nov 27 17:40:12 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Nov 27 17:40:12 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Nov 27 17:40:13 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/5.5.10 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 27 18:41:25 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 27 18:41:34 2016] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 2928)
[Sun Nov 27 18:41:34 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Nov 27 18:41:34 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Nov 27 18:41:35 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/5.5.10 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Check apache logs. That's a good starting point.

Comment: Also post the error log here to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Don't see anything in my error log, but I edited my comment with whats left in my apache log after starting MAMP. I'm just receiving a 500 error using the same URL that had once brought me to the front page of a website I had been working on.

Comment: The error logs dont show much. See if you can get the latest log entry after reloading the page that you having the error with. Also try installing MAMP again to see if the error goes away.

Comment: Also, check this out if it solves your problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/219922/fastcgi-and-apache-500-error-intermittently/442768

Comment: I'm really new to installing WordPress on a local host so I just YouTubed everything. I was about to move over my site from the local host to the server but I installed Sierra and I'm having the same issue. I don't really now how to debug anything so any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: I ended up upgrading to the newest version of MAMP and that seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having trouble with MAMP after having upgraded the Mac operating system to the High Sierra. The Apache Server was not starting. My MAMP is an old version (version 1.9). To solve I just created a folder called logs inside the Library folder. Only that and MAMP returned to normal operation.

I found this solution by seeing in the logs folder. In the Apache log (apache_error_log) I saw that it was looking for the "logs" folder inside the "Library" folder, which did not exist. So just creating this folder solved.